# Using the geodesic equations on the Schwarzschild metric

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

So, I have a multistep problem (in which I have gotten a few of the parts done already), but I am stuck on the rest.

First, the metric.

$$I = (1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1} dr^2 - c^2 (1-\frac{R}{r}) dt^2 = \theta_{1}^2 - \theta_{2}^2$$

Where R is the Schwarzschild radius and c is the speed of light.

So, here is a few of the basic facts that we can see from looking at the metric:

$$\theta_{1} = (1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1/2} dr$$

$$\theta_{2} = c (1-\frac{R}{r})^{1/2} dt$$

$$d\theta_{1} = 0$$

$$d\theta_{2} = \frac{cR}{2r^2} (1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1/2} dr \wedge dt$$

Part A: Find $w_{12} = w_{21} = ?$

I got

$$w_{12} = \frac{cR}{2r^2} dt$$

Part B: Let $z(s) = (r(s), t(s))$ be a geodesic. Derivatives will be taken with respect to s.  Use the first geodesic equation to show that

$$r" = \frac{R}{2r^2} [(1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1}r' - ...$$

I got

$$r" = \frac{R}{2r^2} [(1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1}r' - c^2 (1-\frac{R}{r}) (t')^2$$

My issues arise at part C and beyond.

Part C: Use the second geodesic equation to show that

$$(1-\frac{R}{r})t' = k$$ a constant.

The second geodescic equation is

$$\frac{d}{dt} (\theta_{2}(z')) - w_{12}(z')\theta_{1}(z')$$

Where I have that $z' = r' dr + t' dt$

So, the equation can be rearranged to read

$$\frac{d}{dt} (\theta_{2}(z')) = w_{12}(z')\theta_{1}(z')$$

We have the following

$$\theta_{2}(z') = c (1-\frac{R}{r})^{1/2} t'$$

$$\theta_{1}(z') = (1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1/2} r'$$

$$w_{12}(z') = \frac{cR}{2r^2} t'$$

My question is when I take the derivative of $\theta_{2}(z')$ What variable do I take the derivative with respect to? If I take it with respect to $t$ then I get a $t"$ that I cannot get rid of.

Taking it with respect to $t$

$$\frac{d}{dt} (c(1-\frac{R}{r})^{1/2} t' = c(1-\frac{R}{r})^{1/2} t"$$

$$w_{12}(z')\theta_{1}(z') = \frac{cR}{2r^2} (1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1/2}r't'$$

So we get

$$ c(1-\frac{R}{r})^{1/2} t" = \frac{cR}{2r^2} (1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1/2}r't'$$

If we divide both sides by $c$ and $(1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1/2}$ we get

$$ (1-\frac{R}{r}) t" = \frac{R}{2r^2} r't'$$

The left side is almost correct except a $t"$ in place of $t'$ and I am not sure if the right side is a constant.

If you take the derivative with respect to r you do end up getting

$$(1-\frac{R}{r}) t' = r't'$$

And again I am not sure if $r't'$ is a constant if it is I am done. I know that there was no drdt so t and r should be orthogonal, I am just not sure if that applies to their derivatives as well. I'm gonna guess that is $r'$ dot $t'$ which gives out a number. So it is a constant. The only question is whether or not it is zero.

Part D: The third geodesic equation here would read $\theta_{1}^2 - \theta_{2}^2 = -(c\tau')^2$ where $\tau$ is the proper time. Combine the three geodesic equations to show that

$$r" = -(\frac{Rc^2}{r^2})(\tau'^2)$$

I am not exactly sure which direction to take this. From the first geodesic equation I got this

$$r" = \frac{R}{2r^2} [(1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1}r' - c^2 (1-\frac{R}{r}) (t')^2$$

And from here we see a $\frac{R}{r^2}$ which is in the answer we are looking for. We also see a $(1-\frac{R}{r})t'$ term which should be a constant but it is being multiplied by a $c^2$ and the $t'$ is squared, so I am not sure. We also have $-c^2\tau'^2$ from the third geodesic equation, which is in our answer. But there are still some terms, that I am unsure how to get removed.

The 2 that is being multiplied by $r^2$ the $(1-\frac{R}{r})^{-1}r'$ piece and what exactly happens to the $- c^2 (1-\frac{R}{r}) (t')^2$ piece.

Any advice or tips? Thanks!